# How does laravels IoC/Dependency Injector intsantiate to static instances?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, inversion-of-control

So this is probably a rather simple question but I can't seems to find a very direct answer.  I supposed to could keep reading the source until i figure it out but I was hoping to get a bit of understand of the process of doing so.

I understand IoC and Dependency injection, I am certainly not very experienced in either but I have a good understand of what they are trying to accomplish.  So how does this Laravel instantiate to static instances?  I know it uses PHP reflections but I'm still lost on the part of going from non-static to static methods.  Also I know Laravel is not the only framework to implement such a design but its my preferred and most understood framework.

Comment: Good question! I don't understand it very well either, but it seems to have something to do with the namespaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call a static method on a facade it is being handled by the magic [__callStatic](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.callstatic) method on the `Facade` class. This method gets the underlying class that serves the facade and proxies the static call to it.

Let's look at an example facade:

```
<?php
class MyFacade extends Facade {
  public function getFacadeAccessor() { return "MyFacade"; }
}
```

With this example when we make a call to the class in a static manner such as: `MyFacade::doSomething()` no static method exists on the class. The underlying `Facade` base class however contains a `__callStatic` method that will be called.

[Facade Class Source Code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php?source=cc)

```
public static function __callStatic($method, $args)
{
        $instance = static::resolveFacadeInstance(static::getFacadeAccessor());

        switch (count($args))
        {
                case 0:
                        return $instance->$method();
        // Snipped for brevity...
```

This method then looks up the underlying class to service the facade. If the `getFacadeAccessor` method on the facade returns a string then a matching entry in the application's IOC container is used (i.e. `$app['MyFacade']`). If we returned an object from the `getFacadeAccessor` method it would be used instead (i.e. `public function getFacadeAccessor(){ return new MyClass(); }`

Comment: Awesome thanks for this, I had tried to figure out what was going via the source but had struggled to find the part doing the instantiating. I did not know about the magic __callStaic method either. Cool I can wait to try implement this in my Dependency Injector!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that Laravel instantiate the classes under the hood! In [this](http://fideloper.com/create-facade-laravel-4) site, the guy makes you understanding a little more of the Laravel's core by using it to create a new facade. In the way, he explains how tit works!

It quite simple, actualy:
 1 - You create a classe which extends from Laravel's `Facade` class with a single call like:

```
<?php namespace Name\Space;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class MyClass extends Facade {

    /**
     * Get the registered name of the component.
     *
     * @return string
     */
     protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'myclass'; }

}
```

... that's make Laravel look for `$app['myclass']`. So, the `ServiceProvider` will bind the `myclass` to `MyClass` (according to Laravel's conventions).

2 - For that, of course, you'll have to create a **Service Provider**.
The Service Provider will be responsible for returning the `namespace`, in this case `Name\Space`, for the class(es) that you may want to '*turn into facades*'.

3 - You'll have to register your Service Provider in the `providers` array in the `app/config/app.php`.

Now, if you look with more attention, you'll realise that what Laravel does is just import a namespace and understanding it as it was a class, as well. Under the hood, it will call a instance, but for user (programmer) it will looks like a static call.

I hope I had been clear about it! Look the link I gave to you up there and HAVE FUN! :D

Comment: This is a solid answer, but not quite what I am trying to figure out.  What I want to know is how the facade and IoC actually processes the non static classes to static instances.

Comment: The Service Provider creates a IoC binding. In the above example, the Service Provider would bind something to "myclass". Later, the `MyClass` facade will use the IoC container to resolve "myclass" to whatever is bound to it. Then, the Facade uses PHP magic methods to take any statically called method on the Facade and run it on the resolved object ("myclass" aka an instance of `MyClass`. You [can see that in action here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php#L196).

Comment: Well explained, @fideloper! Could you improve the answer to cover that last part you described?